# Javascript: Create Read More / Read Less Functionality for Blog Posts

Tags: javascript, this

Posted this earlier, but marked a reply as an "Answer" before realizing a limitation that would not work with my code. Reposting my question.

New to JS. I am creating a blog from scratch, and trying to implement a Read More / Read Less button. I was able to get this working on one blog post, but it will be problematic obviously if I try to add the same classes to other blog posts, because then the function won't be sure which objects to act on.

The closest I came to getting it working was this solution provided by another user:

```js
function readMoreFunction(buttonIndex) {
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots")[buttonIndex];
    var contentText = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[buttonIndex];
    var btnText = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonReadMore")[buttonIndex];
    
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
      contentText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read Less";
      contentText.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
```

```css
.content{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Blog Title</strong></p>

<p>Here is an example of the short snippet I want to show by default. <span class="dots">...</span></p>
<span class="content">
<p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction(0)" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>

<p><strong>Blog Title 2</strong></p>

<p>Here is another short snippet I want to show by default for the second blog post. <span class="dots">...</span></p>
<span class="content">
<p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More on the second blog post.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction(1)" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>
```

Basically, when the user clicks "Read More", the ellipses disappear, the hidden content is now showing, and the button changes to "Read Less". When they click "Read Less", the ellipses will be inserted back into the shorter snippet portion, the full content is hidden again, and the button changes back to "Read More."

The problem is, we are passing through an index number that will find the first instance of the "dots" class on the page when we pass through `readMoreFunction(0)`, the second instance of the "dots" class when we pass through `readMoreFunction(1)`, etc. So you'll find that if you switch the (0) and the (1) in the HTML above, the code will no longer work properly. Clicking the "Blog 1" Read More button will try to expand "Blog 2", because it's looking for the second instance of the "dots" class.

This would mean that I need to update the index number being passed through on all of my blog posts every time I add a new one to the top, so that the most recent (top) post is now (0) and the second post is now (1), on through the hundreds of blog posts I may have, which is unreasonable.

How can I write a function to make the "Read More / Read Less" button run independently for all of the different blog posts? I tried to pass through `this` in the `readMoreFunction`, but couldn't figure out how to reference a previous element with a specific id or class name (so that it would grab the most previous span tag that had the id "dots", etc). I could only figure out how to reference the most immediate previous element with `this.previousElementSibling;`

Can you guys help point me in the right direction?

Comment: `Element.style.display` is unknown to your code, unless you assigned it through JavaScript already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are free to edit the html markup, it is recommended to enclose each blog content in a parent element.

By searching the class name starting from the parent element, each element corresponding to the button can be uniquely identified.

```js
function readMoreFunction(el) {
    var parent = el.closest(".wrapper")
    var dots = parent.querySelector(".dots");
    var contentText = parent.querySelector(".content");
    var btnText = parent.querySelector(".buttonReadMore");
    
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
      contentText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read Less";
      contentText.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
```

```css
.content{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<p><strong>Blog Title</strong></p>

<p>Here is an example of the short snippet I want to show by default. <span class="dots">...</span></p>
<span class="content">
<p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction(this)" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<p><strong>Blog Title 2</strong></p>

<p>Here is another short snippet I want to show by default for the second blog post. <span class="dots">...</span></p>
<span class="content">
<p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More on the second blog post.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction(this)" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks nico! This was the easiest way to implement my solution. I tried it in my real code and it works perfectly! I will mark your post as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event inside all buttons: `onclick="readMoreFunction(event)"`

And then inside your function you use `event.target` as reference to clicked button and navigate from there accordingly based on your HTML markup.

```js
function readMoreFunction(event) {
  var dots = event.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".dots")
  var contentText = event.target.previousElementSibling
  var btnText = event.target

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
    contentText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read Less";
    contentText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Blog Title</strong></p>

<p>Here is an example of the short snippet I want to show by default. <span class="dots">...</span></p>
<span class="content">
  <p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction(event)" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>

<p><strong>Blog Title 2</strong></p>

<p>Here is another short snippet I want to show by default for the second blog post. <span class="dots">...</span>
</p>
<span class="content">
  <p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More on the second blog post.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction(event)" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>
```

Comment: Thanks ikiK! I did not know that you could target previous elements of previous elements with "event.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling." Though I accepted the first answer as the post "Answer" because I saw it first, this code also works, and I learned something new. Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: @KatieReynolds Np Kaite, glad it helped. And yeah you can chain everything in JavaScript doom tree traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping each post in a container then access the children through that container only like below thus you'll never face such issues.

```js
function readMoreFunction() {
    var parent = event.target.parentElement;
    var dots = parent.getElementsByClassName("dots")[0];
    var contentText = parent.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
    var btnText = parent.getElementsByClassName("buttonReadMore")[0];
    
    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
      dots.style.display = "inline";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
      contentText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dots.style.display = "none";
      btnText.innerHTML = "Read Less";
      contentText.style.display = "inline";
    }
  }
```

```css
.content{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="conainer-post">
<p><strong>Blog Title</strong></p>

<p>Here is an example of the short snippet I want to show by default. <span class="dots">...</span></p>
<span class="content">
<p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction()" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>
</div>

<div class="conainer-post">
<p><strong>Blog Title 2</strong></p>

<p>Here is another short snippet I want to show by default for the second blog post. <span class="dots">...</span></p>
<span class="content">
<p>Here is the longer text I want to show after the user clicks Read More on the second blog post.</p>
</span>
<button onclick="readMoreFunction()" class="buttonReadMore">Read More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works great! Since the other guy commented before you, I marked his as the Answer, but I appreciate your help with this . You had a slightly different way of doing it than the others so I can file that away for next time I need to do something similar.